# How to set up protractor tests with angular into separate suites?

Tags: angular, protractor

I have an angular application that I have been using protractor to make integration tests that can be run with the ng e2e command. Right now it is set up so that I run the command and it just runs the default plan that is there app.e2e-spec.ts. I want to configure in the angular cli or in protractor the ability to run different plans (test suites). So for example I would like to be able to run "ng e2e all" for example to run a test plan that runs through my whole site. Or "ng e2e login" to run a plan that just tests the login. How do I do this? This is what the e2e folder looks like in the angular project. And what the tsconfig.e2e.json looks like.

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/e2e",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "jasminewd2",
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for the same

Comment: Add a suite to protractor file as suggested below and then run ng e2e --suite=<suitename>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add suites to your protractor.conf.js file.

```
suites: {
  login: './e2e/login/**/*.e2e-spec.ts',
  admin: './e2e/admin/**/*.e2e-spec.ts',
  guest: './e2e/guest/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'
}
```

And then run just the login tests with `protractor protractor.conf.js --suite login`

Comment: I would just add a comment that for an angular the suggested command does not work... What I did was run ng e2e --suite=login .... It works. BUT funny enough a text displayed right afterwards which said "The option '--suite' is not registered with the e2e command. Run `ng e2e --help` for a list of supported options.
" ... But it worked anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage gulp with yargs Click here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs)

```
var args = require('yargs').argv;
gulp.task('e2e-test', ['webdriver_update'], function(cb) {
    gulp.src([]).pipe(gulpProtractor({
        configFile: './path/to/protractor.conf.js',
        args: [
            '--suite', args.suite
        ];
    })).on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }).on('end', cb);
});
```

Then use command -

```
gulp e2e-test --suite example
```

suite tag in conf file would be -

```
suites:{
    example:['./test/e2e/specs/**/*Spec.js',]
  },
```